# variable value is not updating at specific scenario in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom `dropdown` in `angular` app whose html is like this

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
<div class="wrap-drop" id="noble-gases">
    <span>{{selectedCategory}}</span>
    <ul class="drop">
        <li (click)="getReferralsOnSelectChanged()"><a>All Categories</a></li>
        <li *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="categorySelectionChanged(category)"><a>{{category.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i am changing the value of `selectedCategory` variable in my functions inside `component.ts` like this

```
selectedCategory: string = 'All categories';

getReferralsOnSelectChanged = () => {
    console.log('in all categories')
    this.selectedCategory = 'All categories';
    this.getReferrals();
}

categorySelectionChanged = (cat) => {
    console.log('change : ', cat)
    this.selectedCategory = cat.name;
    console.log('selected category : ',this.selectedCategory)
    if (cat._id) {
        this._dataService.get(`${this._const.companySearch}/${cat._id}`).subscribe(res => {
            console.log('category search response : ', res);
            if (res.success) {
                this.referralLinkArr = res.data ? res.data : [];
                this.masterReferralLinkArr = res.data ? res.data : [];
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log('Search Category By referral Error : ', error);
        })
    } else {
        this.getReferrals();
    }
}


getReferrals = () => {
    this.showLoader = true;
    this._dataService.get(`${this._const.companyReferrals}`).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.success) {
            this.masterReferralLinkArr = res.data;
            this.referralLinkArr = res.data;
        }
        this.showLoader = false;
    }, error => {
        console.log('get Referral Error : ', error)
        this.showLoader = false;
    })
}
```

Problem is that when i click any category name in `dropdown` other than `All Categories` so category name updated in template span at this `<span>{{selectedCategory}}</span>`. But when i click on `All Categories` in `dropdown` and after that when i change to any other category name so it's not updating value here in template `<span>{{selectedCategory}}</span>`.

please refer the bug video [here](https://streamable.com/q9rg9)

Comment: Can you share the code for `getReferrals()`? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @AlexK there is no error in console and i included `getReferrals()` code in question post

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue in StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4ednq

Comment: @AlexK no it's working fine. Did you change any thing in your code ?